# Handling null BigDecimals in java8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream, biginteger

I have a `List<BigInteger> listBigInt`. Some of the items are `null` some are not.
I want all the items (except the `null` values) multiplied by five and summed using java8 streams.
So far I fugured out this construct:

```
BigDecimal sum = listBigInt.stream()
    .map(c -> (c == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : c).multiply(new BigDecimal(5)))
    .reduce(BigDecimal::add).get();
```

Is there more elegant way to avoid null values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can gain some more speed by multiplying last:

```
BigDecimal sum = listBigInt.stream()
    .filter(c -> c != null)
    .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
    .get()
    .multiply(new BigDecimal(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually a possible way is to use a filter before the mapping as this:

```
BigDecimal sum = listBigInt.stream()
    .filter(c -> c != null)
    .map(c -> c.multiply(new BigDecimal(5)))
    .reduce(BigDecimal::add).get();
```